# PDFView display page number the way WKWebView shows for pdf

Tags: ios, pdfkit, pdfview

I am trying to use PDFKit for rendering pdf. But I could not find any way to highlight page number while scrolling, the way it is shown in WKWebView.

Do I need to make a custom logic for it?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? I'm also facing a similar situation. I need to show page numbers in PDF thumbnail view. But PDFThumbnailView doesn't have such property.